# How can I make a column sort with column sorting in laravel

Tags: laravel, sorting, model

I have problems when I try to call a model in my view, I don't know how to use completely the sort column, here my classes:

Model

Ordenservicio.php
[image]

Controller

OrdenservicioController.php
[image]

View

System fields not appears
[image]

Comment: can you tell us more about your problem? was it simply because you can't seem to properly execute sorting?

Comment: In future please can you code and paste your code in to your question instead of using images :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$ordenesservicio = OrdenServicio::orderBy('yourColumn','asc/desc')->paginate(5);
```

Where you can only use either ascending or descending order, for example:

```
$ordenesservicio = OrdenServicio::orderBy('yourColumn','desc')->paginate(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make any of your table column sortable than add new column key to your model `$sortable` property. For example,

```
public $sortable = ['no_orden',....,'my_db_key','my_new_db_key']
```

You can also make sortable column from controller,

```
$ordenserviso = OrdenServico::sortable(['no_orden',....,'my_db_key','my_new_db_key'])->paginate();
```

ref : [Kyslik/column-sortable](https://github.com/Kyslik/column-sortable)